# Psalms 48:1; 145:3; translations didn't mention "great is the Lord"?

Tags: psalms, hebrew-bible

Psalms 48:1; DRB;

> 48 Unto the end, a psalm for the sons of Core.

Psalms 48:1; KJV;

> 48 **Great is the Lord**, and greatly to be praised in the city of our God, in the mountain of his holiness.

Psalms 48:1; HOT (the Westminster Leningrad Codex);

> 48 2... גָּ֘ד֤וֹל יְהוָ֣ה...

Also, Psalms 145:3

According to textual criticism, which translation is more accurate?

Why DRB didn't mention "Great is the Lord"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple and uncomplicated.  The Psalms in Hebrew Greek and Latin have slightly different numbering.

The Psalm numbered #48 in Protestant Bibles is #47 in Catholic Bibles.  Let me quote from the footnote to my edition of the Douay-Rheims Bible (The Confraternity Edition of 1948)

The footnote to Ps 9B says this:

> The Hebrew Psalter numbers this second part of Psalm 9, "Psalm 10".
> It also joins Psalms 146 and 147 together.  These changes account for
> the differences in the numbering of the Psalms in Protestant Bibles
> (which follow the Hebrew) and Catholic Bibles.

That is, Ps 48 in Protestant and Hebrew Bibles is the same as Ps 47 in Latin and Catholic Bibles.  (There is also a slight difference in verse numbering within the Psalms as well.)  Allowing for this difference, we note the following text:

Ps 48:1 (Protestant and Hebrew) Bibles is (BSB):

> A song. A Psalm of the sons of Korah. **Great is the LORD**, and greatly
> to be praised in the city of our God, His holy mountain.

Ps 47:1, 2 in DRB is:

> A psalm of a canticle, for the sons of Core, on the second day of the
> week. **Great is the Lord**, and exceedingly to be praised in the city of
> our God, in his holy mountain.

Thus, there is no real dispute here in text.

---

In Ps 145/144 we have a similar matter.

The text of Ps 145:3 from BSB (protestant and Hebrew Bibles) is:

> **Great is the LORD** and greatly to be praised; His greatness is
> unsearchable.

The text of 144:3 in the DRB is:

> **Great is the Lord**, and greatly to be praised: and of his greatness
> there is no end.

Again, there is no real textual dispute here.